# Переподключение к сокету

Tags: node.js, websocket

Есть небольшой сокет-сервер.

Используется nodejs и websocket.

Всё хорошо работает, но, при определённых условиях и нагрузках, бывает что сервер падает. Для таких случае есть forever, который успешно перезагружает сервер в течении нескольких миллисекунд и всё работает в штатном режиме, НО:
все подключенные к сокету клиенты получают закрытие соединения и соответствующие сообщение. Понятно они могут обновить страницу и продолжить работу, но в нашем мире так давно не делают и клиент должен автоматически переподключаться к возобновлённому сокету и продолжить работать, так, что бы для пользователя это вообще было не ощутимо.
Первое что пришло на ум:

```
socket.onclose = function(event) {

    setTimeout(function() {

        var socket = new WebSocket("ws://host:port");

    }, 1000);

};
```

Судя по панели браузера, он успешно переподключается к указанному сокету (который был возобновлён на нужном порту с помощью forever), но вот сообщения новые в сокет и от сокета не проходят (как-будто и нет подключения).

Что я делаю не так и в каком направлении гуглить дальше? Так как попытка найти примеры более правильного и рабочего "переподключения" провалилась.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Новый сокет не подписан на onmessage.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, можно подробнее описать вышесказанное?

Comment: Вы пересоздали сокет но не переподписали его: socket.onmessage = function (evt) { console.log(JSON.parse(evt.data)); }

Comment: После переподключения к сокету повторно "подписываю" сокет.
Теперь отправленные сокетом сообщения - принимаются клиентами.
Но вот отправка не работает. Каким образом теперь её "переподписать"?

Comment: Вероятно переподписать socket.onopen = function (evt) { socket.send("Test message!"); };

Comment: В том то и дело, что вроде как всё "переподписывал".
Но я не учёл тот момент, что js функции у нас бывают как именованные, так и анонимные.
Моя функция отправки сообщения в сокет просто не была видна новому сокету. Поправил, всё заработало. Спасибо.